# What is a full-wave bridge rectifier with capacitor filter and voltage divider?

Tags: rectifier, bridge-rectifier

What is a full-wave bridge rectifier with capacitor filter and voltage divider?  Just a simple definition and an example will do.

Comment: Have you checked out the Wikipedia page on diode bridges? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge

Comment: the voltage divider requirement somewhat puzzles me…

Answer (score 1):

"Full-Wave Bridge Rectifier" is a circuit consisting of 4 diodes that is used to convert Alternating Current into a Direct Current.

However, the output achieved from a simple full-wave bridge rectifier is not stable and is fluctuating in the form of peaks and looking like mountains. To make this output more usable, we use a "Capacitor Filter" so the output voltage is smooth without any ripples.

Edit: As pointed out by 'Peter Jennings', how smooth the waveform can be made depends on the number of capacitors used as well as their value.

And finally, voltage divider is a simple series circuit consisting of resistors that works on the principle of Kirchhoff's Voltage Law and uses the division of voltage across series resistors to achieve a desired voltage.

[image]

(Image source: [Electro Schematics - Capacitor Input Filter Calculation](https://www.electroschematics.com/capacitor-input-filter-calculation/))

Combined, this could be used to convert AC to DC, then smooth out the ripples, and modify the output voltage to get a desired Vout.
Not sure if this helps as I wasn't sure what exactly u wanted to ask but I hope this gives a general idea

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the waveforms in the diagram are typical and depend upon the load and the value of the capacitor. The 1/3, 2/3 times are not set in concrete.

Comment: Nabeel Ali - Welcome :-) I recommend that you read the [tour] and [help] to see the site rules on Stack Exchange sites. One example is that when you include something in an answer (e.g. photo, image or text) which isn't your original work, you need to properly reference it and add a link back to the original source web page, as explained in [this site rule](/help/referencing). I found (what I believe is) the original image that you included in your answer and added the necessary link for you this time, but please add those links yourself in your future answers. Thanks.